# I get lots of warning and errors when installing Clojure in Emacs

Tags: emacs, clojure

I used the EPL package manager and installed the clojure -mode.el  v1.5

I get these errors while installing the major mode

```
In clojure-mode:
clojure-mode.el:174:34:Warning: reference to free variable `paredit-mode'
clojure-mode.el:174:51:Warning: reference to free variable `paredit-version'

In clojure-font-lock-extend-region-def:
clojure-mode.el:210:33:Warning: reference to free variable `font-lock-beg'
clojure-mode.el:217:30:Warning: assignment to free variable `font-lock-beg'
clojure-mode.el:218:33:Warning: reference to free variable `font-lock-end'
clojure-mode.el:220:19:Warning: assignment to free variable `font-lock-end'

In clojure-font-lock-extend-region-comment:
clojure-mode.el:235:26:Warning: reference to free variable `font-lock-beg'
clojure-mode.el:232:49:Warning: reference to free variable `font-lock-end'
clojure-mode.el:236:17:Warning: assignment to free variable `font-lock-beg'
clojure-mode.el:240:17:Warning: assignment to free variable `font-lock-end'

In clojure-indent-function:
clojure-mode.el:357:33:Warning: reference to free variable
    `calculate-lisp-indent-last-sexp'

In clojure-slime-config:
clojure-mode.el:533:11:Warning: assignment to free variable
    `swank-clojure-classpath'

In end of data:
clojure-mode.el:630:1:Warning: the following functions are not known to be defined:
    imenu--generic-function, slime-setup,
    swank-clojure-slime-mode-hook
```

Then when I tried to M-x clojure-install I get

```
cannot find file cmdproxy.exe in the emac's bin folder.
```

What do these mean? I don't want to use the ClojureBox.

Comment: There might not be too many clojure programmers using emacs hanging around here - you could try the clojure google group: http://groups.google.com/group/clojure

Answer (score 4):

Very likely you can ignore the compilation errors (which is what you're reporting in the first block).  Those variables are probably only used when the appropriate packages have been loaded.

Regarding the `cmdproxy.exe` error, it looks like you're running in Windows.  Is that correct?
That executable should be in the same directory as is your Emacs executable.  If it isn't, then you should re-install Emacs.  If it is in that directory, check the value of the variable `exec-path` (by typing `C-h v exec-path RET`) to ensure that the directory containing the Emacs executable is in that `exec-path`.

I've had problems with running subprocesses from Emacs in vanilla Windows (because none of the executables I commonly use are installed, e.g. `diff`).  So I'd recommend installing [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) and running Emacs from a Cygwin shell.  Most notably because the `M-x clojure-install` requires `git` to be installed (if you haven't already installed it).